# Passing extra parameters to source using Jquery UI autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to pass extra parameters for city and state using the jQuery UI autocomplete function.  I've been trying to find an answer to this for a while but can't seem to find something that works for me.

My current code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#id_place").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/autocomplete_place",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term,
                    city: $("id_city").val(), 
                    state: $("id_state").val(),
                    test: 4
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
    });
});
```

The autocomplete works, but its not passing my city and state parameters to the function.  If I type `v` it requests the URL: `/autocomplete_place?term=v&test=4`

I'm guessing its evaluating the `val()` of city and state upon `(document).ready()` and getting blank values for these form fields?  I thought making source into an ajax function would solve that, but perhaps not.

Any ideas?

Comment: I wanted to do this in rails 3.1
finally figured it out and put it in a [Gist on github](https://gist.github.com/1870941)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you missing a # in your selector `$("#id_city").val()?`

Comment: Wow, I actually was missing it.  Haha, hours of trying to figure this out and that was the error.  Thanks!

Comment: I think every programmer has been there some time. I have personally spent days in the past debugging just to find errors like this.