# pass parameters to autocomplete using jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have read this post: [Passing extra parameters to source using Jquery UI autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939801/passing-extra-parameters-to-source-using-jquery-ui-autocomplete)
I am develping a Web Page in Asp.net C#.

My HTML code:

```
 <input class="tags" to_search="Birds" />
 <input class="tags" to_search="Animals" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".tags").autocomplete({
          source: "GenericHandler.ashx?name="+$(this).attr("to_search")
    });
});
```

I want to pass the `to_search` attribute of the `<input>` tag to generic handler.
Above code is calling `GenericHandler.ashx` but gives null value of `name`.
How can I get `name` value equals to the `to_search` attribute of `<input>` tag?
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you don't add any `.tags` during runtime, you can do this.

```
$('.tags').each(function(i, tag) {
    $(tag).autocomplete({
        source: 'GenericHandler.ashx?name='+ $(tag).attr('to_search')
    });
});
```

I also suggest you use data attributes in your input tags like this.

```
<input class="tags" data-search="Birds" />
```

resulting in the final solution,

```
$('.tags').each(function(i, tag) {
    $(tag).autocomplete({
        source: 'GenericHandler.ashx?name='+ $(tag).data('search')
    });
});
```

In the event that you do add a element to your document dynamically you can do this.

```
// jquery object of the new element created
var element;

element.autocomplete({
    source: 'GenericHandler.ashx?name='+ element.data('search')
});
```

Comment: thanks @Austin, its working perfect. One quick question: If I add any `.tags` runtime, do I need to call above function after adding `.tags` dynamically? will it work fine?

Comment: Yes you would need to run that snippet again. But it would be more efficient if you just binded `.autocomplete` to the element individually after you add it to the document. I've updated my answer to include that scenario

Answer (score -1):

Just Pass like this

```
$('#txtCropname').autocomplete('Handler/CropSearch.ashx', { extraParams: {ids:'new'} });
```