# jQuery UI to send additional value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to usejquery auto complete. when the autocomplete is requested, I want a value from another textbox to be sent as well. However the value doesnt get sent from the other text box. please help.

HTML:

```
    <form>
    <input type="text" id="stat" name="stat" />
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" />
    </form>
```

jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
    source:"backend.asp?typ=getcity&stat="+$("#stat").val()
    }); 
    }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: you should do the `.autocomplete` on the city whenever the `stat` has changed. Otherwise it won't get updated.

Comment: @ Pedro: can you please write the code for me so that I can understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `ajax` in `source` like,

```
$(function(){
    $("#city").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "backend.asp",
                dataType:'json',
                data: {
                    type: 'getcity',
                    stat: $("#stat").val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
    });
});
```

Refer [Passing extra parameters to source using Jquery UI autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939801/passing-extra-parameters-to-source-using-jquery-ui-autocomplete)